# \displaystyle and \mathbf with cmbright font

Tags: fonts, fontsize, bold, displaystyle

I would like to use bold symbols in superscript equations. To do so, I use `\displaystyle` as in

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
    $e^{\mathbf{A}t}=e^{\displaystyle \mathbf{A}t}=e^{{\displaystyle \mathbf{A}}t}$
\end{document}
```

The corresponding output is:

[image: good output with cmroman]

The first exponential is exactly what I'm looking for.

Now, if I add the `cmbright` package, the corresponding code

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{cmbright}
\begin{document}
    $e^{\mathbf{A}t}=e^{\displaystyle \mathbf{A}t}=e^{{\displaystyle \mathbf{A}}t}$
\end{document}
```

yields:

[image: image showing problem with cmbright]

As one can see, in the left exponential the A symbol is not bold, and the other symbols are larger (as expected with `\displaystyle`).

I guess there is a pretty simple explanation about `cmbright` but I am not aware of it. Any clues to get the bold symbol AND the normal size with `cmbright`?

Comment: Try `\mathbold{}`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For mysterious reasons, the `.fd` file for the OT1 encoding defines a substitution rule for the bold font at sizes less than 9pt and chooses a non bold font, instead of scaling the only available font (at 10pt).

Cure it by redefining the font shapes.

```
\documentclass[border=3pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{cmbright}

\DeclareFontFamily{OT1}{cmbr}{\hyphenchar\font45 }
\DeclareFontShape{OT1}{cmbr}{m}{n}{%
  <-9>cmbr8
  <9-10>cmbr9
  <10-17>cmbr10
  <17->cmbr17
}{}
\DeclareFontShape{OT1}{cmbr}{m}{sl}{%
  <-9>cmbrsl8
  <9-10>cmbrsl9
  <10-17>cmbrsl10
  <17->cmbrsl17
}{}
\DeclareFontShape{OT1}{cmbr}{m}{it}{%
  <->ssub*cmbr/m/sl
}{}
\DeclareFontShape{OT1}{cmbr}{b}{n}{%
  <->ssub*cmbr/bx/n
}{}
\DeclareFontShape{OT1}{cmbr}{bx}{n}{%
  <->cmbrbx10
}{}


\begin{document}

$\mathbf{A}\mapsto e^{\mathbf{A}t}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This answers my question even more accurately than Sigur's, but I already accepted Sigur answer... Thank you

Comment: @anderstood, it is up to you. Feel free. We all learn a lot with egreg's posts.

Answer (score 6):

From the documentation [cmbright package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/cmbright) you can use the `\mathbold{}` command.

But the `A` is in italic shape.

[image]

Comment: The fact that A becomes italic seems more logical to me :) Is there any drawbacks to replace all \mathbf commands with \mathbold?

Comment: You can try `\renewcommand{\mathbf}[1]{\mathbold{#1}}`

Comment: I did so and did not see any drawbacks in my present document, but maybe you knew some which could cause me trouble in the future, if I stopped using \mathbf.

Comment: If you stop using `cmbright` package the command `\mathbold` would not be defined anymore and then you simply comment that line with `%`.

Comment: Thanks for making me be aware of the `\mathbold` command. I got used to it, but never understood why bold symbols became non-italic! Now I'll try to get used to this more logical typo.